# File time stamp does not change with data update

Tags: windows, file-io, timestamp

I have a customer which claims that he has an application which updates some data in a log file without changing the time stamp of that log file.

Why would any application behavior as such?

Comment: There are Creation Time, Modification Time and Access Time. Does the customer see the Modification Time?
And only as a guess: When will the underlaying file system set the modification time? At write or at close operation? Does the app close the file?

Comment: It is the modification time. I am not sure whether the app close the file.

Comment: Application name is websphere and file name is system.out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a new FEATURE of Windows 2008 (R2), Windows 7 and up. Modified time is not updated anymore like it used to in Windows 2003.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/asiasupp/archive/2010/12/14/file-date-modified-property-are-not-updating-while-modifying-a-file-without-closing-it.aspx

And

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winservergen/Thread/2B8BACA2-9C1B-4D80-80ED-87A3D6B1336F

Answer (score 0):

There is a good workaround for build automation:

```
copy /b <Filename> +,,
```

I found this trick here: https://superuser.com/questions/292630/how-can-i-change-the-timestamp-on-a-file.
The strange is that "copy /?" does not say about /b option.

Answer (score 0):

I know, this is a very poor C# workaround for some special cases. My server writes a log and I need to get the file changes using a `FileSystemWatcher`.

So, everytime my log file is updated I create a new empty file with the same name but the extention ".update".

```
try
{
    string updateFlagFile = Path.ChangeExtension(myLogFilename, ".update");
    using (File.Create(updateFlagFile))
    { }
}
catch (Exception)
{ }
```

My `FileSystemWatchers` tracks this file and I know that the log was updated.