# EnterpriseLibrary flat file logging not updating modified date

Tags: .net, enterprise-library, enterprise-library-6

Observed Behavior: The log files date modified property does not update when new log entries are written to the file.

Expected Behavior: The date modified property is updated as new entries are added to the file.

Use Case: I am attempting to employ a log monitoring tool (log.io) that monitors a given set of log files for changes and pipes those changes in real time to a browser interface. This is working fine with the exception of log files written by Enterprise Library which don't announce themselves as updated via the date modified property until another process touches the file. That is, if I open the file via notepad, log.io immediately picks up the changes. Until I do, nothing happens.

Questions: Is there any way to configure EnterpriseLibrary to force date modified updates through the flat file listener? Are there logging libraries that don't have this issue with flat file logging?

Comment: This is a "feature" of newer Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226513/file-time-stamp-does-not-change-with-data-update