# PHP filemtime() not working - cache problem?

Tags: php, caching

I am calling filemtime() from a PHP file executed by POST from a JavaScript/HTML app. It returns the same time stamp for a separate test HTML file every two seconds even when I edit the test file with a text editor and I can see its DTM change in the local file system.

If I reload the entire app (Ctrl+F5), the timestamp reported stays the same. At times (once after 4 hours) the time stamp changes, but I don't know what makes this happen.

The PHP part of my code looks like this:

```
clearstatcache(true,$FileArg);
$R=filemtime($FileArg);
if ($R===false)
    echo "error: file not found";
else
    echo $R;
```

This code is called by synchronous Ajax, given only its PHP filename, using setInterval every 2 seconds.

Windows 10 Home, Apache 2.4.33 running locally for HTTP access, PHP 7.0.30 .

ADDED:

The behavior is the same in Firefox, Chrome, Opera, and Edge.

Comment: What happens if you try the old "hack" `$R=filemtime($FileArg . "?" . time());` to give it a "unique filename" each time

Comment: Is the $fileArg a local or 'remote' file?

Comment: What is the exact time (hour minutes seconds) your webapp reports?

Comment: Andreas: (1) I tried it and got an error, since this is a direct filesystem function, which does not accept queries. Only URLs accept queries. (2) $fileArg is a local file (test.html) in the same directory as the other files in my app.

Comment: Kasper, there is no exact time. The timestamp is for a random time in the past, maybe a few minutes or hours. As I said, I don't know what causes it to be updated.

Comment: Why did someone vote down the question? I spent quite a bit of time on this, searched the Web for help, and did experiments. You guys are rough!

Comment: When editing the file, do you close it after write, or keep it open? Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226513/file-time-stamp-does-not-change-with-data-update

Comment: What code is used to edit the test.html? Can't you use that code to write the modification time somewhere?

Comment: Andreas, unfortunately, no. My tool suggests that users edit their HTML file to add id attributes to certain elements, which are needed by JavaScript  code at runtime. I don't want to add an entire text editor to my tool, which would be necessary to do what you're suggesting. So the user edits the file and my tool needs to detect that it is edited and ready to be rescanned so the user can continue working on it in the tool. DTM is perfect for this.

Comment: Kasper Agg, I use an ordinary text editor, which closes the file. If the file were being held open, my tool would not be able to open it at all. But reading the file into a window using JavaScript window.open never fails.

Comment: Keeping a file open should not prevent other applications from reading, but from the link I shared, it seems as if Windows holds a local DMT in memory, and only writes the actual DTM data once the file is properly closed. Could you verify that even after completely closing all instances of your favorite text editor, the DMT is still unaffected?

Comment: Kasper, I just tried the following test: ran my app, then edited the test file, then closed my editor. The DTM stayed at 1544403604 throughout all this. Then I reloaded the app. Still 1544403604. So closing the editor had no effect. I've checked Windows' DTM and it seems updated in the directory immediately upon the saving of the edit.

Comment: Ok, ruled that one out too. I'm running out of idea's. If this persists, and you need a nother way, you could try a Windows system command like ls that shows the DTM. Maybe it's more accurate?

Comment: No "maybe" about it. I already reported that Windows shows the DTM correctly. It is not as easy to capture the output if a Windows command as it is in Linux. My backup plan is simply to have the user click a button to refresh when they have done their edit. I'd rather get DTM working, though. Could Ajax be caching the POST output from the PHP page? I can test this...

Answer (score 1):

The results are being cached: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php

> Note: The results of this function are cached. See clearstatcache() for more details.

It almost sounds like Windows is doing some write caching...

stat() on the other hand has an additional note:

> Note:
>
> Note that time resolution may differ from one file system to another.

Maybe worth checking stat output.

**edit**

Maybe it's a bug, or Windows not playing nice, but you could also do a `shell_exec` with the Windows command showing DTM.

Comment: Here is stat output. Sorry if the format gets messed up by being in a comment, but Stack Overflow disallows answers to comments as Answers. 12/8/18 (some info deleted to fit into comment space)
  7 => 1215,
  8 => 1544297383,
  9 => 1544297383,
  10 => 1544184990,
  11 => -1,
  12 => -1,
  'dev' => 2,
  'ino' => 0,
  'mode' => 33206,
  'nlink' => 1,
  'uid' => 0,
  'gid' => 0,
  'rdev' => 2,
  'size' => 1215,
  'atime' => 1544297383,
  'mtime' => 1544297383,
  'ctime' => 1544184990,
  'blksize' => -1,
  'blocks' => -1,
)

Comment: Time resolution does NOT differ between file systems because Timestamp is a standard format, in seconds only. Anyway, I'm only running on Windows.

Comment: Given the fact that the timestamp has quite a specific time does seem to prove that it's not a resolution issue. What I meant was that if the OS keeps a max resolution of 4h, you could tell by the similarity in DMTs of files. Ruled this one out at least.

Comment: Kasper, yes, it is ruled out because Windows supports DTM just fine. It seems to be a bug in my program, but I haven't found it yet. And I never said the timestamp is just one specific value. It stays at one specific value until I'm away from the computer for some time then return, then it jumps to the value of when I returned.

Comment: I don't think your code is wrong, the fact that it does work after four hours makes me think it's Windows (wouldn't be the first time)...

Answer (score 0):

**News**: it turns out to be an ordinary bug in my app. I copied my Ajax call and forgot to edit it to apply to the test file. So it applied to one of my app files instead and the DTM only got updated when I edited that app file (FTAdjust.js).

When I specify the correct test file, the DTM updates just fine each time I edit it in another process.

It can sometimes be hard to find one's own bug even when it stares one in the face! I kept looking everywhere else but where the mistake was.

Is there a way to delete a thread from Stack Overflow, since it is irrelevant to others?